# Extract string dynamically after a certain character SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to extract a certain phrase from a column after a/any symbol.
For example, If I want to extract *Tutorial* from *SQL-Tutorial*, following query shall suffice.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('SQL-Tutorial', 5, 8) AS ExtractString;
```

What if I want to extract everything before or after '-' or '_' from the following fields in a column?

- SQL-Tutorial
- Oracle-Tutorial
- IBM DB2-Tutorial
- Sybase ASE-Tutorial
- PostgreSQL-Tutorial
- MariaDB-Tutorial
- MySQL-Tutorial
- Teradata-Tutorial
- IBM Informix-Tutorial
- Amazon SimpleDB-Tutorial

Comment: Because I came along only range based solutions `(...al', 5, 8)`. That's why I got stuck and need direction.

Comment: Well, perhaps you need to do better research. Have you thought about googling "SQL Server string functions"? There are `charindex`, `left`, `right`, `len` and `stuff` - all of which can be useful to get what you want.

Comment: @fasihullahkhan try to use string_split function to get before and after symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([COLN] varchar(24))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([COLN])
VALUES
    ('SQL-Tutorial'),
    ('Oracle-Tutorial'),
    ('IBM DB2-Tutorial'),
    ('Sybase ASE-Tutorial'),
    ('PostgreSQL-Tutorial'),
    ('MariaDB-Tutorial'),
    ('MySQL-Tutorial'),
    ('Teradata-Tutorial'),
    ('IBM Informix-Tutorial'),
    ('Amazon SimpleDB-Tutorial')
;
SELECT  PARSENAME(REPLACE(coln,'-','.'),2) [before],
 PARSENAME(REPLACE(coln,'-','.'),1) [after]  from #Table1
```

output

```
before           after
SQL              Tutorial
Oracle           Tutorial
IBM DB2          Tutorial
Sybase ASE       Tutorial
PostgreSQL       Tutorial
MariaDB          Tutorial
MySQL            Tutorial
Teradata         Tutorial
IBM Informix     Tutorial
Amazon SimpleDB  Tutorial
```

Comment: The temp table name and the select statement table name don't match

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server the below code can extract everything before and after the char '-', the where condition is there to validate if there is a char '-' in first place to split like that

```
SELECT 
LEFT([COLUMN],charindex('-',[COLUMN])-1) as BeforeString,
RIGHT([COLUMN],len([COLUMN])-charindex('-',[COLUMN])) as AfterString
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE charindex('-',[COLUMN])<>0
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX to get before and after of any character like -

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,0,CHARINDEX('-',@String,0)) As Before_str,
  SUBSTRING(@String,CHARINDEX('-',@String)+1,LEN(@String)) As After_str
```